# Capture ID of At Command in R

Tags: r, linux, at-job

Problem: I want to capture the id of the at command job

This is the normal code to execute the at command

```
> system(command="echo touch my_path/test_file.in | at 05:26 AM")
```

And this is the output

```
job 984 at 2015-12-11 05:26
```

Since I want to capture that id of the at command so I added the "intern" parameter of the system() function and save the id to a variable

```
> id<-system(command="echo touch my_path/test_file.in | at 05:26 AM", intern=TRUE)
```

Still the output was not captured so I tried the system2() function

```
> id<-system2(command="echo touch my_path/test_file.in | at 05:26 AM", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE)
```

Still not working. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system2()` quotes the command so you probably want to use something like

```
id <- system2(
      "sh",
      c("-c","echo touch my_path/test_file.in | at 05:26 AM"),
      stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE
     )
```

Alternatively, you can stick to `system()` and re-direct `stderr`:

```
id <- system("echo touch my_path/test_file.in | at 05:16 AM 2>&1", int=T)
```